# I am trying to do arithmetic on table values and keep getting an error. here is my code

Tags: lua

I am trying to perform arithmetic on table values and keep getting an error. Here is my total code.  I am basically trying to generate simplex noise.  I have created a multidimensional array (table) and am trying to perform operations on the values but i keep getting an error that says I cannot perform arithmetic on a table value.  I don't know If I have to convert it to something or what. Please Help.

```
totalNoiseMap = {}

function simplex_noise(width, height)
   simplexnoise = {}
   for i = 1,512 do
       simplexnoise[i] = {}
       for j = 1, 512 do
           simplexnoise[i][j] = 0
       end
   end
   frequency = 5.0 / width

   for x = 1, width do
       for y = 1, height do
           simplexnoise[x][y] = noise(x * frequency,y * frequency)
           simplexnoise[x][y] = (simplexnoise[x][y] + 1) / 2
       end
   end

   return simplexnoise
end

function noise(x, y, frequency)
    return simplex_noise(x / frequency, y / frequency)
end

function generateOctavedSimplexNoise(width,height,octaves,roughness,scale)
    totalnoise = {}
    for i = 1,512 do
        totalnoise[i] = {}
        for j = 1, 512 do
            totalnoise[i][j] = 0
        end
    end
    layerFrequency = scale
    layerWeight = 1
    weightSum = 0

    for octave = 1, octaves do
        for x = 1, width do
            for y = 1, height do
            totalnoise[x][y] = (totalnoise[x][y] + noise(x * layerFrequency,y * layerFrequency, 2) * layerWeight)

            end
        end

        --Increase variables with each incrementing octave
        layerFrequency = layerFrequency * 2
        weightSum = weightSum + layerWeight
        layerWeight = layerWeight * roughness

    end
    return totalnoise
end

totalNoiseMap = generateOctavedSimplexNoise(512, 512, 3, 0.4, 0.005)
```

Comment: Do I need to convert it somehow. I just am stuck.

Comment: Keep getting what error?

Comment: the error is attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is my entire function.  I just can't find anything on google about how to perform arithmetic on table values. sorry... just new to forums.

Comment: Your **entire** function? What is `width`? What is `height`? What is `totalnoise`? What is `layerFrequency`? What are `x`, `y`? Can people reproduce the problem with this code snippet? What is this code trying to do? What error did you get?

Comment: sorry...I was trying to add my entire function to the comment but didn't know how.

Comment: Don't put the code in the comment, **Edit** your question.

Comment: `noise()` returns a table, what do you expect `noise(x * layerFrequency,y * layerFrequency, 2) * layerWeight` do?

Comment: I get it now....  I have to find a way to add two tables together.  I think I can use metatable functions to do it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You should use local variables in functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalnoise[x][y] + noise(x * layerFrequency,y * layerFrequency, 2) * layerWeight
```

Here you get table `noise(x * layerFrequency,y * layerFrequency, 2)`, mult it by scalar `layerWeight` and than add it to scalar `totalnoise[x][y]`.

I can think of how to multiply table by scalar  - it should be something like

```
for i = 1,512 do
   for j = 1,512 do
       a[i][j] = t[i][j] * scalar
   end
end
```

But I'm unable to get what you're trying to do by adding. Suppose it should be addition of two tables

```
for i = 1,512 do
   for j = 1,512 do
       a[i][j] = b[i][j] + c[i][j]
   end
end
```

But it works only with same-sized tables